# Unable to locate form submit button

Tags: python, selenium, automation

```
option = ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
driver = Chrome(chrome_options=option) #getting the web driver object
try:
    url="https://www.groupon.fr/merchant/center/"
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    email="xyz"
    password="abc"
    email_box=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("emailInput"))
    email_box.send_keys(email)
    password_box=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("passwordInput"))
    password_box.send_keys(password)
    attempts=0
    while True:
        try:
            submit = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"submitButton button-primary button-cta")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)
            break
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            attempts+=1
            if (attempts>3):
                raise Exception("Error")
            continue
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

**Output**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "", line 22, in  submit =
>   WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"submitButton
>   button-primary button-cta"))) File
>   "C:\Users\sheik\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
>   line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   TimeoutException: Message:

I am actually trying to login on this page and after filling the email and password, I am unable to find the submit button although I am using the correct class name of the button. I have tried it from xpath too but no success.

What is the issue in my code?[The html of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhcFP.png)

Comment: What is it supposed to do? You have provided next to no information. Everyone has better things to do than try to figure out what your code is supposed to do. Please edit your question to provide background and context.

Comment: It would be good if you share the html code of the part as well.

Comment: I have updated the query. The html image of the page is attached. Kindly bear with me since its my first post here and I am struggling with it.

Comment: The problem is that you are using `By.CLASS_NAME` but sending it 3 class names, "submitButton button-primary button-cta". Either choose one of the three or turn it into a CSS selector and use all three, e.g. Justin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have selenium installed yet on my new machine but you can search using [CSS selectors](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples).
I know the example code is not python but you should be able to figure out the corresponding python code.

Edit. Try the following:

```
submit = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".submitButton.button-primary.button-cta")))
```

Comment: Ok so this solved my issue. Although I don't know how. But great, thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `By.CLASS_NAME`, does not work for matching on multiple classes". The CSS selector allows you to match on multiple classes.

Comment: Unique but the button had three classes, not one. The `By.CLASS_NAME` will not work when you supply all three at the same time. The CSS selector, however, allows you to search for an element with, in this case, three classes.